# All my textures are stretched vertically in Spritekit/Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures, skspritenode

Let's say I have a basketball texture made up of pixel art and it's 21x21. I put it in the game:

```
ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
ball.position.x = CGFloat.random(min: 0 , max: self.frame.width)
ball.position.y = self.frame.height + ball.frame.height * 2
ball.zPosition = 1
ball.size = CGSizeMake(21 , 21)
ball.setScale(10)
ball.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest
//then all the physics stuff
self.addChild(ball)
```

but when they spawn, the pixels are stretched vertically, and when the balls roll, it's always stretched vertically-so the problem seems to be rooted somewhere in the engine. What should I try next?

Thanks yall

Comment: Most likely something is set up wrong in your view controller, in particular where you set the scaleMode and size of the scene.  Would you mind including that portion?

Comment: @gliderman in my GameViewController.swift inside of the viewdidload it says  scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill -- although I'm pretty sure that is just for my menu scene which is rendering fine, but when I go into the actual game the textures are messed up.

Comment: @gliderman I added a *scenename*.scaleMode = .AspectFill to all my transitions between scenes and that fixed it.

Comment: @gliderman now it seems to change the relative positions of things, the scene is definitely wider, when I try to position something in the top left it's totally off screen...

Comment: what happen if you remove ball.size = CGSizeMake(21 , 21) and ball.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest ?